# Expression blend & WPF

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

suddenly i found wpf project type is there in expression blend. i just do not understand why people create WPF project from expression blend because for that VS IDE is there. i am new in wpf so please tell me in what situation user will create wpf apps from expression blend and also tell me what is the difference between expression blend & VS2008 IDE wpf project type..
please explain in detail.thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projects are the same - you can even arbitrarily switch between the applications at any time (given both applications are installed).

Expression Blend has much better visual designer and is purposed for UI designers and artists, Visual Studio is better for writing the C# code behind and is meant for programmers.

Answer (score 1):

`Blend` is used to *Design* XAML screens. Generally, designers prefer `Blend` over `Visual Studio`.

And since both (Programmers and Designers) can work on same project, `Blend` supports creating and opening VS projects.