# Dynamically creating Expression Blend controls in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I have created a button in Expression Blend 4. I want to dynamically create instances of this button at run time.

The code for the button is below:

```
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="139" Margin="46,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

In addition to the supplying the code can you put comments in explaining what you are doing so that I can learn the general principle.

I know this is a simple question so I have been reading up places such as: [Expression blend & WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066945/expression-blend-wpf), [Is there a way to "extract" WPF controls of Expression Blend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356024/is-there-a-way-to-extract-wpf-controls-of-expression-blend), and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ffa981b8-9bba-43a2-ab5e-8e59bc10fc0d/ unfortunately none of these have helped.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a `Style`.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more like what is a style, where some good places are to learn about styles. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Brett WPF Tutorial is great: http://www.wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Comment: Thanks, that is a great resource. Unfortunately not really related to what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WPF application you should have a `App.xaml` file, in there you can add `Styles` that are to be used thoughout your UI.

Example:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication8.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!--The style for all your buttons, setting the background property to your custom brush-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> <!--Indicate that this style should be applied to Button type-->
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Or if you dont want to apply to all buttons, you can give your `Style` a `Key` so you can apply to certain Buttons in your UI

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication8.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <!--Add a x:Key value so you can use on certain Buttons not all-->
        <Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}"> 
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To use this `Style` on a `Button`, just add a binding to the `Style` property of the `Button`

```
  <Button Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyle}" />
```

this will apply the `Style` just to this `Button`

Or if you really want to do it in code behind you can just add the `Brush` you want to the background

```
   Button b = new Button
   {
       Background = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.White, new Point(0.5, 1), new Point(0.5, 0))
   };
```

its very easy to translate xaml to code because xaml uses the exact same property names, like the code brush I posted above:

```
new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.White, new Point(0.5, 1), new Point(0.5, 0))
```

is ....

```
Brush(firstColor,secondColor,StartPoint EndPoint)
```

Xaml just accesses properties in the button, they will all have the same names in C#.

Comment: I was expecting something more like `Button NewButton = new button();`. This is all XAML. I think we must have got off track some how.

Comment: if you use the first example I posted every time you crate a new button it will look like the one you made in Blend.
`Button NewButton = new button();` with the style in App.xaml will look like your blend one

Comment: added code only example, if you really want to do it that way

Comment: I really do want to code it. How did you know what the code was? In particular the bit about the background is unintuitive. Is there a website or other resource I can lookup to learn this stuff?

Comment: what do you mean you dont want to code it? and I knew what the code was because YOU pasted the code in your question

Comment: I want to code it. Take for example the bit about the background, it can't be worked out by looking at the XAML alone. There must be some way to know how to convert XAML into c# code. Is there a webpage on MSDN or other resource I can lookup to learn this stuff?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21615/discussion-between-brett-and-sa-ddam213)

Comment: I showed you how to create the background in code?
`new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.White, new Point(0.5, 1), new Point(0.5, 0))` =

Comment: Yes but you didn't explain how you knew what to do. For example how would I generalise what you wrote to, for example, work out how to position the control. By the way grateful for all help so far.